# Remote connection to SQL Server - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I'm currently setting up a remote SQL Server. Made all steps regarding remote connection (as found on http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/).

Let's say my servers are :

- WEB
- SQL

I can connect from WEB, using SQL Server Management Studio, to my SQL Server using my connection string. Using the same connection string in my `web.config` does not work, keep getting error 26 - Error locating server.

Connection string:

```
Data Source=169.254.196.1,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need to specify the port number of 1433 since that's the default port. can you ping from web to SQL? is the instance name correct?

Comment: It does not work even with a colon. As stated, the same connection string work in MSSL Management Studio (installed on WEB server) but not in IIS.

Comment: Also, instance name is not stated in the connection string. And no, I cannot ping since server doesn't respond to ping request BUT, as I said, I can connect on WEB using MSSQLMS to SQL, with the same exact connection string.

Comment: Is this on a LAN or over the web? 169.254 is a strange address to connect to. This address indicates that the server could not obtain an IP address so it designated it's own. In short a 169 address means you probably don't have connectivity. If you go on to the SQL Server and type `ipcofing /all` what do you get? I know you have connected from SSMS but something isn't adding up.

Comment: It's a LAN in vSphere. SQL server doesn't have access to internet, WEB does, and I can connect to WEB from SQL server has well. So both VM are communicating each other.

Comment: I suggest you use a UDL to confirm a test connection to the SQL Server http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test.aspx. Then open the UDL in notepad and use that exact connection string.